# Why set a second parameter in the translate function?

Tags: theme-development, translation

The second parameter in the translate function is optional, but I always see people use it and some don't.

So I want to know if I should use it or not and if yes, how I will use it later.

I asking this because I'm new to this, and I'm using *e() and _*() right now in my theme, and I'll learn how to translate it when I finish.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to WPSE Peter,

The second argument is a *translation domain*. This is essentially where the translation for the first argument can be found. By default it checks the WordPress language folder - but if you are creating a custom theme or plug-in, 
you cannot rely on the translation for that string to be there (after all the WordPress language folders only contain translations for WordPress, not your plug-in/theme).

The setup is different for plug-ins, but to register a text domain for themes you use [`load_theme_textdomain`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/load_theme_textdomain):

```
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'my_theme_setup');
function my_theme_setup(){
    load_theme_textdomain('my-unique-theme-domain', get_template_directory() . '/languages');
}
```

The first argument is the domain name, which is passed as the second argument in `_e()` and `__()`. The second is where the translation files can be found.

See Codex for [`_e()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_e) and [`__()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_2).